# How to use Range.InsertDatabse to insert a Oracle Databse table in the word document using c# in visual studio

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I am trying to create a word document using c#, In the word doc I want to import a table directly from Oracle database. As I can see there is `Range.InsertDatbase` option available, but I am unable to figure out the syntax for using that.

Or  is there  any other way to directly import a oracle db table in doc using c#?